# pass multiple arrays and values into javascript function

Tags: javascript

How to pass arrays and values into javascript function.
fund and agent pass as an array.
fromDate and toDate are pass as a single variable.

```
function fetch_javaScript(fund,agent,fromDate,toDate)
         {
           -------
           -------

           var agent = document.getElementById('agent').value;
           var fromDate = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
           var toDate = document.getElementById('toDate').value;
           var queryString = "?fund=" + fund_name ;
           queryString +=  "&agent=" + agent ;
           queryString += "&fromDate=" + fromDate;
           queryString += "&toDate=" + toDate;
           ajaxRequest.open("GET", "final_ajax.pl" +
                              queryString, true);       
         }


        <tr><td>
           <h2>Funds</h2>
           </td>
           <td><select name="Funds" id="fund" multiple >
                  <option value="Select">Select</option>
                  <option value="PMF">Principal</option>
                  <option value="PRAMERICA">Pramerica</option>
                  <option value="JM">JM</option>
                  <option value="DHL">DHL</option>
                  <option value="EMF">Edelweiss MF</option>
                  ----
                  ---- 
          </select> <br></td>
        </tr>       


         <tr><td>
             <h2>Agents</h2>
             </td>
         <td><select name="Agents" id="agent" multiple>
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                <option value="Gyanesh">Gyanesh</option>
                <option value="Satish">Satish</option>
                <option value="Sailesh">Sailesh</option>
                <option value="ArchanaMuluguru">Archana</option>
                ----
                ----    
         </select></td>
         </tr>
```

I'm able to pass single variables into query string like that

?fund=PMF&agent=Balaji&fromDate=5-8-2013%209:33:6&toDate=10-8-2013%209:33:14

problem with array.

```
 How can I build a querystring looks like that?
```

?fund[]=["PMF","JM"]&agent[]=["Balaji"]&fromDate=5-8-2013%209:33:6&toDate=10-8-2013%209:33:14

fund and agent are array types it is depend upon user it select single value or multiple value.
fromDate and toDate are single values

Comment: fund and agent are passed to javascript as array, or to your ajax request or both?

Comment: ajax request is also there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to get multiple selected options from select:

```
function get_selected_data(o){
    var selectedOptions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < o.options.length; i++){
        if(o.options[i].selected){ 
            selectedOptions.push('"' + o.options[i].value + '"');
        } 
    }
    if(selectedOptions.length){
        return '[]=[' + selectedOptions.join(',') + ']';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

For example:

```
var queryString = "?fund" + get_selected_data(document.getElementById('fund'));
queryString +=  "&agent" + get_selected_data(document.getElementById('agent'));
queryString += "&fromDate=" + fromDate;
queryString += "&toDate=" + toDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the toString Javascript function

> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp

Comment: w3schools is a terrible resource. Here's a better one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString. Anyways, this is a link-only answer, and we don't want link-only answers here. Can you write a code sample on how that function should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Use serialized json array like this and send data via post

```
{

"fund":[
    "value1","value2"
    ],
    "agent":
    ["value1","value2"],
    "fromdate":"value",
    "todate":"value"
    }
```